# BeautifulSoup: How to get the non-comment-content of a class with comments?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get data from a webpage using `BeautifulSoup`. It works fine for the most data, but one class seems to work different and I can't figure out what to to. Are comments maybe affecting `soup.find_all`?

So I have a webpage with several classes having the same name and I'm finding the contents with `soup.find_all`. While this works for the `class "points column"`, which always looks like this:

```html
<div class="points column">Punkte</div>
<div class="points column">45.677</div>
<div class="points column">43.445</div>
...
```

It doesn't work for the `class "teamValue column"`, which looks like this:

```html
<div class="teamValue column">Teamwert</div>
<div class="teamValue column">
<!-- react-text: 690 -->
554,4
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 691 -->
 €
<!-- /react-text -->
</div>
<div class="teamValue column">
<!-- react-text: 705 -->
449,7
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 706 -->
 €
<!-- /react-text -->
</div>
...
```

This is my code:

```
def getplayerdata(self):
    bot = self.bot
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bot.page_source, 'html.parser')

    playervalue = soup.find_all("div",class_="teamValue column",text=True)
    playerpoints = soup.find_all("div",class_="points column",text=True)

    print(playervalue)
    print(playerpoints)
```

The output for `playerpoints` works as expected, I get all the data and can extract only the text with the `.string` command.

But for `playervalue` I only get one element in my list, which is:

```
[<div class="teamValue column">Teamwert</div>]
```

Comment: use `find_all()` without `text=True`. And use `.get_text()` or `.text` instead of `.string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get this text if I use `find_all()` without `text=True` and `.get_text()` or `.text` instead of `.string`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

text = '''<div class="teamValue column">Teamwert</div>
<div class="teamValue column">
<!-- react-text: 690 -->
554,4
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 691 -->
 €
<!-- /react-text -->
</div>
<div class="teamValue column">
<!-- react-text: 705 -->
449,7
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 706 -->
 €
<!-- /react-text -->
</div>'''

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_items = soup.find_all('div',class_="teamValue column") #text=True)


for item in all_items:
    print('1>', item.text)

for item in all_items:
    print('2>', item.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))

for item in all_items:
    print('3>', item.string)
```

Result:

```
1> Teamwert
1> 

554,4


 €


1> 

449,7


 €


2> Teamwert
2> 554,4 €
2> 449,7 €
3> Teamwert
3> None
3> None
```

Comment: This works, thank you all! I don't even need (strip=true, seperator=' '), it works the same way only with get_text().

Comment: I put `(strip=true, seperator=' ')` to show that `get_text()` has options and sometimes it can do more then `.text`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `text= False` :)

```
playervalue = soup.find_all("div",class_="teamValue column",text=False)
print(len(playervalue))
```

Out:

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use soup.select and re.sub to get rid of the new lines

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''
<div class="teamValue column">Teamwert</div>
<div class="teamValue column">
<!-- react-text: 690 -->
554,4
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 691 -->
 €
<!-- /react-text -->
</div>
<div class="teamValue column">
<!-- react-text: 705 -->
449,7
<!-- /react-text -->
<!-- react-text: 706 -->
 €
<!-- /react-text -->
</div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
team_values = [re.sub('\n+', '',item.text) for item in soup.select('.teamValue.column')]
print(team_values)
```

[image]